# Sql Server 2008 Select From table with AND style conditions in related tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Given a model like this
[image]

ProductFacets contains the following data:

```
ProductId, FacetTypeId
1, 1
1, 2
2, 1
2, 3
3, 4
3, 5
4, 1
4, 2
```

I'd like to be able to select all Products which have a FacetTypeId of 1 AND 2.
The result set should contain ProductIds 1 and 4

Comment: Why is/should 2 not be included in the result set of 1, 4 ? (Notice the ProductID, FacetTypeID of 2,1 )

Comment: FacetTypeId must be 1 and 4 (What about products that may have 1, 4 and 2)

Comment: Think of it as a filter where we only want the Products with BOTH FacetTypeId 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return rows for products that have only facet types 1 and 2, and only those facets.

```
SELECT ProductId,
    COUNT(*) AS FacetCountByProduct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FacetTypeId in (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FacetCountSelectedFacets
FROM ProductFacets
GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    and SUM(CASE WHEN FacetTypeId in (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Product PROD WHERE PROD.ProductId IN(

SELECT P.ProductId pId FROM ProductFacets AS P 
WHERE P.FacetTypeId = 1 

AND EXISTS  
(
  SELECT *
  FROM ProductFacets AS P1 
  WHERE P1.FacetTypeid = 2 
        AND P1.ProductId = pId
)

AND NOT EXISTS  
(
  SELECT *
  FROM ProductFacets AS P2 
  WHERE P2.FacetTypeid NOT IN (1,2) 
        AND P2.ProductId = pId
)

)
```

There must be a better way to solve this, but it's the only one i can come up with

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a way to do this:

```
select distinct ProductId from ProductFacets 
where ProductId in (select ProductId from ProductFacets where FacetTypeId = 1)
and ProductId in (select ProductId from ProductFacets where FacetTypeId = 2)
```